# Angular UI Tinymce deletes content from ng-model and 2-way binding does not work when not using `<textarea>`

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, tinymce, angular-ui

One problem I am having with TinyMCE editor and Angular UI's light wrapper is that ng-model doesn't appear to do the 2-way binding that I would expect with the model data on the scope when changes are made in the editor. This problem only seems to happen when `<div>` or `<p>` is used.

The 2-way binding seems to work just fine when I use `<textarea>`, but this is not what I want... I want an inline editor.

Here are my options:

```
$scope.tinymceOptions = {
    inline: true,
    menubar: false,
    statusbar: false,
    toolbar: "bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link | removeformat"
};
```

In my case, if there is content in `pageElement.text`, it will actually get put into the TinyMCE editor just fine. **However**, once TinyMCE does this, the text is deleted from `pageElement.text` altogether, and the `ng-model` binding that it has to `pageElement.text` is no longer being respected:

```
<div class="pageParagraph">
    <div class="contenteditable"
         ui-tinymce="tinymceOptions"
         ng-model="pageElement.text"></div>
    <p>{{pageElement}}</p>
</div>
```

Here's a screenshot:

[image: Displaying inline problem]

How can I get 2-way binding to occur when TinyMCE is in inline mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After an hour or so of mucking around, I figured that changing `updateView` in tinymce.js from the Angular UI extension fixes the issue:

```
      updateView = function () {
        if(elm.prop("tagName").toLowerCase() === 'textarea') {
            ngModel.$setViewValue(elm.val());
        } else {
            ngModel.$setViewValue(elm.html());
        }

        if (!scope.$$phase) {
          scope.$apply();
        }
      };
```

It's probably not perfect, but it will work for p, div and textarea. This solution also avoids non-obvious code that looks strange.

Answer (score 0):

You should set `$watch` to your inline editor and if it was changed set content to TinyMCE editor as follows:

```
tinymce.get('my-tinymce-id').setContent($scope.inlineEditorContent);
```

Comment: I don't think this solves my problem. You are using `<textarea>` in your plunker example, which causes the correct 2-way binding that one would expect, so the extra interaction with tinymce's object is not needed. The problem is when the editor is being used as inline with a `<div>` or `<p>` tag. The content on the scope does not get modified any longer. In fact, it just gets deleted altogether. Change your plunker to `<div>`, and you'll see that it no longer works.

Comment: Also, watches no longer work when you don't use the `<textarea>` as well.

Answer (score 0):

What about this approach:

http://plnkr.co/edit/iMa0WxWkO4OVBZC86u8W?p=preview

I used `<div>` and `<p>` there.

Comment: Hrm, this does solve the TinyMCE -> Angular problem, using an interesting approach. Is there a way to set its initial content though? Passing in the model with some content seems to not actually change the editor when using this approach.

Comment: I am curious why they made the binding only work for textarea elements. Maybe I should put forth some effort to changing the angular ui code to make it work for everything.

Comment: Binding work not only for `textarea` but also for the `input` and `select`. For other tag's you can't bind model yet. See this page:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17784266/ng-model-binding-not-working-on-div

This is the example with initial content:

http://plnkr.co/edit/emdvVl8vIlRSkbR4JQ08?p=preview

Comment: I figured out an alternative solution that fixes the Angular UI binding code itself. I think they fix the project to do something similar.

Comment: Yes, your approach is much more elegant!