# angularJS and ng-model strange behavior

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

Question is simple - why this work like this work?

```js
angular.module('test1', [])
    .directive('myDir', function() {
        return {
            replace:true,
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<input type="text">',            
        };
    }).directive('nogo', function() {
        return {
            replace:true,
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<div><input type="text"></div>',            
        };
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="test1">
    <my-dir ng-model="test"></my-dir>
    <nogo ng-model="test"></nogo>
    <input type="text" ng-model="test"/>
</body>
```

The only difference between two directive is that template for second wrapped with 'div'.

But one work, another doesn't.

Really - I don't understand - why working one is on. But it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem here is that you are applying the model to the `<div>`, [here is another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17784266/ng-model-binding-not-working-on-div) with more information about this problem.

And in this particular case you can change the bind into the template in order to make it work.

```js
angular.module('test1', [])
    .directive('myDir', function() {
        return {
            replace:true,
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<input type="text">',            
        };
    }).directive('nogo', function() {
        return {
            replace:true,
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<div><input type="text" ng-model="test"></div>',            
        };
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="test1">
    <my-dir ng-model="test"></my-dir>
    <nogo ng-model="test"></nogo>
    <input type="text" ng-model="test"/>
</body>
```

Also on the [`ng-model`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) docs says:

> The ngModel directive binds an input,select, textarea (or custom form control)

Comment: Thanks, but I know about "input/select/textarea". Main question is - why does first example work? If I made custom-directive, and use ng-model, then it automatically binds to template to special tags ("input/select/textarea")? But if there are  two inputs? Then Angular ask me to wrap it with root-tag, right? <DIV>, for example, and default binding will switch off??

Answer (score 1):

the problem is ng-model does not work on div.

change :

```
.directive('nogo', function() {
        return {
            replace:true,
            restrict: 'E',
            template: '<div><input type="text"></div>',            
        };
    });
```

to

```
.directive('nogo', function() {
    return {
        replace:true,
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div><input ng-model='test' type="text"></div>',            
    };
});
```

dont forget to remove ng-model from `<nogo>*remove ng-model*</nogo>`
it is working..

Comment: I don't get it. ng-model does not work on div? I did NOT ask it for that. Why binding is working in first example - I do NOT any point to ng-model!! Can you point me to documentation, that can explain that? I know about restrict for root-tag on template, but can't link all it together.